# Rails 7 Destroy not working and only running Show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm new to Rails. I want to write a delete for my reviews. I followed the code in the tutorial. Here is the code in the show page

```
<% link_to "Delete this review", review_path(@review), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }  %>
```

Here is the code in the controller

```
 def destroy

    # find the individual review page, delete it then redirect to home page
    @review = Review.find(params[:id])
    
    #deleting the review
    @review.destroy

    #redirect to home page
    redirect_to root_path

end
# end of destroy
```

There is no error, no confirmation, no action at all. When I checked the command line, I noticed the reviews#show is working whenever I click the destroy link -

> Started GET "/reviews/4" for ::1 at 2022-05-03 19:58:13 +0630
> Processing by ReviewsController#show as HTML
> Parameters: {"id"=>"4"}
> Review Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "reviews".* FROM "reviews" WHERE "reviews"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
> ↳ app/controllers/reviews_controller.rb:51:in `show'
> Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
> Rendering reviews/show.html.erb within layouts/application
> Rendered reviews/show.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 0.7ms | Allocations: 271)
> Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 7.5ms | Allocations: 2265)
> Completed 200 OK in 10ms (Views: 8.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms | Allocations: 3049)

How do I fix it?

Comment: `<% link_to "Delete this review", @review, data: { turbo_method: :delete, turbo_confirm: "Are you sure?" }  %>`

Comment: Do you have the proper route setup in your `routes.rb` file?

Comment: @BenFenner thats not the issue. If the route didn't exist you would get a routing error. Instead this is just another variation of the age old problem where jquery ujs, rail ujs or turbolinks doesn't work and the link is just doing what links do - sending a GET request. This is probally 20% of the questions on the Ruby on Rails tag and you can't just close them as duplicates because their are so many potential reasons why the JavaScript in not working.

Comment: Right now Rails still includes Rails UJS which has an event handler for `data-method`. Turbolinks uses `data-turbolinks-method` so we are going to see a lot more of this question because people haven't updated their code or are using outdated learning materials.

Answer (score 2):

I somehow was able to fix this. I read a few more blogs. And it's the javascript thing happening.
First, I tried the following two methods but they only make GET requests:

1.
`<% link_to "Delete this review", review_path(@review), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }  %>`

2.
`<% link_to "Delete this review", review_path(@review), data: { turbo_method: :delete, turbo_confirm: "Are you sure?" }  %>`

***My Solution***

When I created my rails project, it didn't include the javascript; ***application.js*** in the asset (I don't know why but I'm still trying to find out).
So I created it manually and added the following code:

```
//= require_tree
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Next, I went to my gemfile and added the line `gem 'jquery-rails'`

And ran `bundle install`

Then, I went back to my application.html.erb and added the javascript_include_tag:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

Finally I edited the link in the show.html.erb:

```
<%= link_to "Delete this review", @review, data: { 'method': :delete, 'confirm': "Are you sure?" } %>
```

And it finally made a DELETE request.
I'm still baffled by my conclusion. There are a lot of discussions going around regarding "method calls" with version changes. My solution might not be the best approach but I can at least continue with this. I would love to hear your thoughts on it as well.

Thank you for all the input.

Answer (score 1):

**As taken from the Ruby on Rails Guide 7.0.4**:

> Clicking links always results in an HTTP GET request. If your
> application is RESTful, some links are in fact actions that change
> data on the server, and should be performed with non-GET requests.
> This attribute allows marking up such links with an explicit method
> such as "post", "put", or "delete".
>
> Turbo will scan  tags in your application for the turbo-method data
> attribute and use the specified method when present, overriding the
> default GET action.

```
<%= link_to "Delete post", post_path(post), data: { turbo_method: "delete" } %>
```

**For confirmations**:

```
<%= link_to "Delete post", post_path(post), data: { turbo_method: "delete", turbo_confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
```

Also worth mentioning that the `destroy` method in my controller is:

```rb
def destroy
  @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  @event.destroy
  redirect_to events_path, status: :see_other
end
```

[Replacements for Rails/UJS Functionality - 5.1 Methods](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#method)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and got it to send a DELETE by changing to from link_to to button_to.

Im not sure how this works so if you can give a reason let me know below. Thanks!

```
<% button_to "Delete this review", review_path(@review), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }  %>
```

Comment: Id assume that by default, link_to always sends a GET so unless you wana play with your routes and such, a button_to will do the job. I dont get why it wont work if i define 'delete' in my controller since 'edit' works fine with a link_to and its not a GET request either.